# IF ELSE in Excel for Mac 2016

Tags: excel, macos, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to make the third argument in this function so that the "value if false" is a blank cell. I have tried every which variation of how to leave a blank cell if the first argument is not true as well as researched this site and google. It just does not work for me, perhaps because I'm using Mac Excel 2016? And advice on the formula here is much appreciated:

```
=IF(FIND("quality",A80),SUBSTITUTE(A80,A80,"A quality life demands quality questions")," ")
```

The screen shot below shows how I entered the formula and got #VALUE! errors for cells not TRUE to first argument.

[image]

Comment: Let me know if any issues viewing the screenshot image of my excel sheet.

Answer (score 2):

FIND() returns an error if the value is not found and a number if it is.  It does not return True/False or 0 if not found.

If the FIND() is an error the IF becomes an error

So you need to wrap it in something to test for the error.  I like to use ISNUMBER() as it will return a True/False depending on whether the FIND returns a number or not.  As an Error is not a number it will return FALSE when the item is not found in the string

Also using `SUBSTITUTE(A80,A80,"A quality life demands quality questions")` in this case is a little redundant as you are replacing the whole string with another.  Simply putting `"A quality life demands quality questions"` is sufficient.

One more note; `" "` returns a single space, use `""` or `TEXT(,)` to return an empty string:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("quality",A80)),"A quality life demands quality questions","")
```

Comment: It's worked, thank you! An instructor told me to use the SUBSTITUTE part of the function. But this is cleaner, thanks!

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.